# CodeDeploy gets stuck on Install or AfterInstall

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have codedeploy setup with same appspec file for 6 different deployments. While the codedeploy works perfectly for some of the deployments, it gets stuck on others.

The issue is, it gets stuck on random environments on random basis, sometimes on Install phase and sometimes on AfterInstall phase. It also gets stuck on one of the multiple servers inside same deployment.

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
   - source: /
     destination: /var/www/html/current
permissions:
   - object: /var/www/html/current
     pattern: "**"
     owner: root
     group: www-data
     mode: 644
     type:
       - file
   - object: /var/www/html/current
     pattern: "**"
     owner: root
     group: www-data
     mode: 755
     type:
       - directory
hooks:
   BeforeInstall: 
    - location: scripts/beforeinstall.sh
      runas: root
   AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/afterinstall.sh
      runas: root
```

**beforeinstall.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

php artisan cache:clear
hostname >> /tmp/bhostname.txt
crontab -r
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = horizon ] 
then
    hostname >> /tmp/ahostname.txt
    cd  /var/www/html/current/backend && sudo php artisan down
    sudo supervisorctl stop laravel-worker:*
    sleep 30
    sudo service supervisor stop
    
    sleep 30
    rm -rf /var/www/html/current/backend/bootstrap/*
    rm -rf /var/www/html/current/backend/storage/*
    rm -rf /var/www/html/current/backend/worker.log
else
    cd  /var/www/html/current/backend && sudo php artisan down
    rm -rf /var/www/html/current/backend/bootstrap/*
    rm -rf /var/www/html/current/backend/storage/*
fi
```

**afterinstall.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/current/backend/bootstrap
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/current/backend/storage
cd  /var/www/html/current/backend && sudo php artisan cache:clear
cd  /var/www/html/current/backend && sudo php artisan view:clear
cd  /var/www/html/current/backend && sudo php artisan config:cache

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/var/www/html/current/backend/storage/gcp_translate.json

# (crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/2 * * * * cd /var/www/html/current/backend/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1")| crontab -
echo  "*/2 * * * * cd /var/www/html/current/backend/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1" > /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
echo  "* * * * * /bin/chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/html/current/backend/storage/logs" > /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
echo  "0 0 * * *  rm -rf /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root" > /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
service cron restart

if [ "$HOSTNAME" = horizon ] 
then
    cd /var/www/html/current/backend && php artisan up
    cd /var/www/html/current/ && pwd && ls -altr && mv laravel-worker.conf  /etc/supervisor/conf.d
    sudo service supervisor restart
    sleep 30
    sudo supervisorctl restart laravel-worker:*
fi

service  php7.4-fpm  restart
service nginx restart
```

Comment: Did you try to login to the instance and run the scripts manually? This could provide some extra info what fails?

Comment: Could you also provide the error message if there is one in case of "getting stuck"?

Comment: @Marcin yes I did, the script ran flawlessly.

Comment: @ChKl, there's no error message. CodeDeploy remains in the stuck state.
I even checked the logs inside EC2 for AfterInstall script, the success logs were there but the state stayed in progress

Comment: Passed after stopping the 2 stuck deployments after an hour, and restarting them.
Seems like an issue from AWS side, but I only have basic support plan.

Comment: You can check AWS Health in your console to see if there are any notifications about CD issues?

Comment: @Marcin, thanks, it's a good pointer. Unfortunately I don't see any notifications, but I did found the feedback window and have reported the issue to AWS.

Comment: You can answer your own question with any details if you have and accept it as well.

Comment: @Marcin sure, I'll add details after I get response from AWS. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by reducing build size.

The build used to be around 900 MB after packaging as .zip file. After trimming it down to 600 MB, AWS CodeDeploy is not getting stuck on random basis.

The build was trimmed by removing node_modules (1.7 GB without compression) from frontend.

Therefore, I conclude the issue to be inadequate size of servers (t3.medium) with regards to the highly compressed bigger builds.